# Divi - I've hide the global header and footer and cannot find a way to enable again

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, themes, divi

I've tried to use the frontend builder from Divi to hide the header and footer of the checkout page through Custom css (display:none) at the section settings.
The problem is that this disabled the Global Header and Footer and I can't see the items anymore to remove the code.
I've tried to enable again through the code #main-header { display:block!important; } but it did not work
Any ideas where can I find this code so I can erased it?

Seems like if I create a new template works but I can't find a way to enable the old one.

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why my previous comment was deleted since this solution absolutely solved my problem. But here I go again, in case bouzina farid's answer does not work for some reason.

I've managed to solve the problem by using the tool "Export model" from Divi's Theme Builder. With the raw code in hands I've searched for the tag "display:none", remove the tag, save it and imported again.

Answer (score 0):

if you've built your header through the theme builder, try to use this CSS
code

```
.et_pb_section_0_tb_header {
    display : block;
}
```

it worked for me

and just for remark, you can remove the global header from one page without the need for custom CSS
check this blog post to know-how https://diveindivi.com/remove-the-header-and-footer-of-your-divi-website/

Comment: Thank you bouzina farid ! Your method is probably simpler.

I forgot to answer my own topic but I did manage to solve it by using the tool "Export model" from the Theme Builder. Then I've search the raw code for the tag "display:none", remove it and imported again. Kind of a dumb solution but it did the job so... There you go, if someone have the same problem this are two ways to fix it.